# In React, how to convert country code to country name, using country-data?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, redux, country-codes

Using [country-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data), I thought I could do

```
npm install --save country-data
```

and then in the code:

```
import CountryData from "country-data";
```

and use

```
CountryData.countries["TW"]
```

to get the country data, and

```
CountryData.countries["TW"].name
```

to get the name. But `CountryData.countries["TW"]` gets `undefined` already. How can it be done? Are there possible better alternatives to using `country-data`?

P.S. the npm page and [github page of country-data](https://github.com/OpenBookPrices/country-data) has some info on how to use it with webpack, which I suspect is needed to be used with React. But I did them:

```
npm install json-loader --save-dev
```

add to webpack.config.js:

```
// ...
   loaders: [
      // other loaders
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' },
  ],
// ...
```

and it doessn't work yet.

Comment: Have you tried: `import { countries } from "country-data";`?

Comment: your line should be doing the same thing as my code...

Comment: "destructured" imports are not *exactly* the same as what you are doing.  `import/export` have a `default` object that is exported from a `modules.exports`.

Comment: I tried your line and it is giving `undefined` too

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the `npm module` incorrectly

According to the **[docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data)** you can do it as follows

```
npm install --save country-data
```

And import it like

```
import {countries} from 'country-data';
```

and then use it like

```
console.log(countries["TW"].name);
```

Comment: `countries["TW"]` is already `undefined`, so the name will give an error too

Comment: @DavinTryon In the docs they have used the require method and the equivalent of require in import is as shown in the example above

Comment: Have you changed the import too since the above node module may not have a default export

Comment: how do you change the import?

Answer (score 2):

Try **country-list** library

```
   const { getCode, getName } = require('country-list');

   console.log(getCode('Belgium')); // BE

   console.log(getName('BE')); // Belgium
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
var CountryData = require('country-data');
console.log(CountryData.countries['TW']);
```

It works an outputs as such

```
{ alpha2: 'TW',
  alpha3: 'TWN',
  countryCallingCodes: [ '+886' ],
  currencies: [ 'TWD' ],
  emoji: '',
  ioc: 'TPE',
  languages: [ 'zho' ],
  name: 'Taiwan',
  status: 'assigned' }
```

It could be because of how the module is exported?

This also works

```
import CountryData from 'country-data'
console.log(JSON.stringify(CountryData.countries['TW']));
```

Outputs as such

```
{"alpha2":"TW","alpha3":"TWN","countryCallingCodes":["+886"],"currencies":["TWD"],"emoji":"","ioc":"TPE","languages":["zho"],"name":"Taiwan","status":"assigned"}
```

Comment: for some reason, if I add those two lines `import CountryData from 'country-data';
console.log(JSON.stringify(CountryData.countries['TW']));` to my project, it also prints out `undefined`

Comment: What version of 'country-data' are you using trying wiping node_modules and re installing them maybe?

Comment: I just did the install 2 hours ago, so it should be current... and when I look into package.json, it says `"country-data": "0.0.31"`

Comment: do you use the line `CountryData = require('country-data');` even when you use React?

Comment: dear @nonopolarity were you able to resolve this issue? as I am facing same issue in same library. quite weird.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787946/array-is-behaving-differently-at-different-line-in-javascript-react?noredirect=1#comment125142607_70787946